# How to write a click event on apply button in the ag grid filter

Tags: filter, apply, ag-grid-angular

I'm trying to implement ag grid for the first time in my angular project and I am learning out the things now. I came across a situation where I have to call a method on a click of apply button in the filter. So anyone please help me with how to handle a click event on apply button in ag grid filters. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any way to get access to the filter's button or it's event. I think that you'll probably have to write a custom filter component.